# Where can I find a tiny, clamp-on, battery-powered LED light for taking high magnification macro shots in the field?

Tags: lighting, macro

None of the standard clamp lights work for this purpose as they are all better suited for reading books in bed, or barbecuing at night. If I want to photograph very small subjects at close range, with directed light, I need an articulated, dimmable, very bright LED light source....will I have to build it myself or can I buy one somewhere?

Comment: Something like this? https://www.google.cz/search?q=macro+light+ring&client=opera&hs=Sf0&biw=1920&bih=1100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfv-Lr3urRAhXDSxoKHU_iDkkQsAQIKg

Comment: Thanks for the link, Crowley....but I'd eliminated the use of a ring light. When attached to a lens, and used to build macro-image stacks, the location of the light changes as focus is moved through the image plane...disastrous for aligning stacks!. Both my subject and light source must be fixed in space. Ring lights also illuminate a subject much too uniformly for my purposes. I'd prefer a directional, single point-source lighting.

Comment: You ought to specify that in your question - as a ring-light is the first thing anyone will think of.

Comment: https://www.dollartree.com/LED-Clip-On-Mini-Spotlights/p333808/index.pro

Comment: https://www.dollartree.com/LED-Translucent-Clip-On-Book-Lights/p338182/index.pro

Comment: Small LED lights, buy their very nature aren't usually dimmable. They're usually either on or off.

Comment: @MichaelClark LEDs brightness is driven by current. With simple pulse width modulator (easiest way is Arduino) and capacitor you can dim any LED array. You should use a relay if you wan to use powerful LEDs. You can also use voltage divider (potentiometer), but it might be tricky to set up.

Comment: @Crowley You *could*, but there aren't really any *tiny* ones commercially available, are there? I'm just pointing out that there aren't really many (any?) options available that are "...tiny, clamp-on, battery powered..." that are also "...articulated, dimmable, very bright..." LED lights.

Comment: @MichaelClark I hope 1A is enough: https://www.gmelectronic.com/optorelay-el3083-dip6 . If not, divide the array into segments where it is enough and use multiple SSRs (Solid state relay)

Comment: Would something like [Venus Optics KX-800](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1165604&gclid=Cj0KEQiAiMHEBRC034nx2ImB1J0BEiQA-r7ctlmYvaKJla7_x2uWCt7kKLtjwAKYFt8QgYDQ8QXffm8aAm6b8P8HAQ&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&c3api=1876%2C92051678882%2C&Q=&A=details) work for you? Put your camera on one tripod and this on a flash stand and it should meet all your criteria.

Comment: When using a macro mounted to bellows, I have to get in so close to my subject that conventionally sized lighting cannot fit between my subject and the lens. At 12mm dia., even my studio fiber optic light is too big. I may have to modify a conventional clip-on LED with an acrylic "light pipe" that I can sneak into that tight space. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a [Gorillatorch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002IT5DIU). I have no affiliation with this product other than it works and that my wife bought two for exactly that purpose. One will suffice but sometimes you want to fill in shadows.

The Gorillatorch seems to exactly fit your description: directed, articulated, dimmable and very bright.

Answer (score 1):

Option one: Buy magnifying [glass with illumination](http://www.ges.cz/cz/stolni-lupa-s-osvetlenim-prl-12b-led-GES07403311.html), remove the lens and shoot through it.

Option two: Use the ring from above, remove much more parts, and make a mout to a camera (use the screw now dedicated to tripod).

Option three: Do-it-yourself. Make a ring array of LEDs and design the power supply and dimming. Look for articles and recommendations regarding pulse width modulation and rectifiers. If in doubt, or struggle, search through and ask [Electrical Engineering here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com). You can use one type of LEDs, or, use several types - with different spectra, aka "temperatures", and power them separately.

Comment: For a shading you can cover appropriate part of the ring, or, when  DYI approach is chosen, divide rings into several blocks and power them separately.